# venv/bin/python -m jupyter nbconvert fails with error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

`venv/bin/python -m jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb` fails with the following error:

`Error executing Jupyter command 'nbconvert': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

How can I make it work?

The following works:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb
```

Comment: Do you get the same result if you supply the full path for the notebook? If you're not calling the command from the same directory the file is in it won't be able to find it.

Comment: @Topperfalkon the error is with nbconvert not being found, not the notebook.ipynb file. I've solved it, see my answer

Comment: My apologies I was being a bit dense. Congrats on figuring it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I realised that this is due to the way the `jupyter` binary loads extensions.

There is a `jupyter-nbconvert` binary that works in the virtual environment:

```
venv/bin/jupyter-nbconvert notebook.ipynb
```